# Python, coding Split bill

Tags: python, function, split

Questions

Write the function `split_bill(total, num_people)` that takes in a total pre-tip bill amount and the number of people and calculates how much each person should pay.

Assume a 20% tip and that the bill is split evenly. The function should print out a sentence in the form `“Each person pays {amount} dollars.”` but should not return anything.

For simplicity, do not worry about rounding cents to the nearest hundredth.

Here is my code, and I am not sure what is the problem

```
`def split_bill(total, num_people):
     tip == total ** 0.2;
     split_bill == (tip + total) / num_people
     print ("Each person pays" + 'split_bill' + "dollars")
     return` 


'def test_split_bill(total, num_people):
      print("Testing split_bill(total, num_people)...", end="Each person pays" + 'split_bill' + "dollars")
      assert(split_bill(10, 3) == None)  # prints "Each person pays 4.0 dollars."
      assert(split_bill(55, 4) == None)  # prints "Each person pays 16.5 dollars."
      assert(split_bill(0, 9) == None)   # prints "Each person pays 0.0 dollars."
      assert(split_bill(73, 5) == None)  # prints "Each person pays 17.52 dollars."
      assert(split_bill(109, 8) == None) # prints "Each person pays 16.35 dollars."
      print("... done!")'
```

[image]

Comment: add a `print`  statement in the `split_bill`

Answer (score 0):

After reading the directions a couple of times, I think you might just be missing the period (".") after "dollars".

My solution:

```
def split_bill(total, num_people):
   answer = (total + (total * .2)) / num_people
   print(f"Each person pays {answer} dollars.")
```